# React Native: How to retrieve image file content from fetch?

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

In my React Native 0.62.2 app, a fetch is used to fetch an image `IMG_1885.jpg` from cloud object storage for test purpose:

```
let img = await fetch(bgimage.uri, {
          method:"GET",
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
        });
```

Here is the http return and is assigned to variable `img`:

```
'img in sp ', { type: 'default',  //<<<==output of img
                             │ status: 200,
                             │ ok: true,
                             │ statusText: undefined,
                             │ headers:
                             │ { map:
                             │ { 'x-oss-storage-class': 'Standard',
                             │ 'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
                             │ 'content-md5': 'Au4QpWK3O8+l4qCYxDjzw==',
                             │ 'content-length': '475266',  //<<<==size of file
                             │ connection: 'keep-alive',
                             │ 'content-type': 'image/jpeg',   //<<<<==jpeg
                             │ 'x-oss-server-time': '20',
                             │ 'x-oss-object-type': 'Normal',
                             │ date: 'Sun, 05 Jul 2020 21:20:16 GMT',
                             │ 'x-oss-force-download': 'true',  //<<<==server force frontend to download
                             │ 'content-disposition': 'attachment',
                             │ 'x-oss-request-id': '5F024410980C637340B8FBD',
                             │ 'last-modified': 'Sun, 05 Jul 2020 17:26:04 GMT',
                             │ etag: '"02EE10A562B73BC23E978A826310E3CF"',
                             │ 'x-oss-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 
                             │ 'x-oss-hash-crc64ecma': '65781719895705534',
                             │ server: 'AliyunOSS' } },
                             │ url: 'https://oss-hz-1.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/IMG_1885.jpg?Expires=1593984273&OSSAccessKeyId=myID&Signature=mySigna',
                             │ bodyUsed: false,
                             │ _bodyInit:
                             │ { _data:
                             │ { size: 475266,
                             │ offset: 0,
                             │ blobId: '7f5f3eb5-8e02-470a-a06c-81bcd1161df8',
                             │ __collector: {} } },
                             │ _bodyBlob:
                             │ { _data:
                             │ { size: 475266,
                             │ offset: 0,
                             │ blobId: '7f5f3eb5-8e02-470a-a06c-81bcd1161df8',
                             └ __collector: {} } } }
```

The http status is `200`, the content size matches the test file.

Here is the output of `img.blob()` which has no image data:

```
[14:20:16] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'img blob ', { _data:  //<<<== output of img.blob()
                             │ { size: 475266,
                             │ offset: 0,
                             │ blobId: '7f5f3eb5-8e02-470a-a06c-81bcd1161df8',
                             └ __collector: {} } }
```

`img.json()` returns error: `[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '�']`

How to retrieve the image content from `img` returned?

Comment: Can the approach in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679178/read-binary-data-from-blob-to-display-image-react-native